# find items inside and include layout

Tags: android, layout, include, toolbar

I know this question has been asked before, but the solutions offered have not helped me thus far.

I have a basic layout:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/test_toolbar"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/maths_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/maths_view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

the include layout:

**test_toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello workd"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I want to find the TextView inside my include layout.

Code I've tried so far but hasn't worked:

```
Toolbar toolbar= findViewById(R.id.test_toolbar);
TextView toolbarTitle= toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
toolbarTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

How can I find the views inside the include layout?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple mistake:
In your code, you do `findViewById` with the wrong ID. The id needs to be the id of the include layout.

Change this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.test_toolbar);
```

To this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
```